# Vincenty Direct formula Latitude issue

Tags: c#, .net, geospatial

I'm using Mike Gavaghan's Geodesy library to calculate:

**The new Latitude & Longitude from a starting Location, Bearing and Distance ( Vincenty direct formula, CalculateEndingGlobalCoordinates)**

However, I am seeing some results I did not expect.

When using the Direct formula, calculating a new point Due East (90 degrees), I expected the Latitude to NOT change, However the following code returns unexpected results:

```
GeodeticCalculator geoCalc = new GeodeticCalculator();
        Ellipsoid reference = Ellipsoid.WGS84;
        Angle startBearing = new Angle(90);
        double metersDistance = 50000;

        GlobalCoordinates dest = geoCalc.CalculateEndingGlobalCoordinates(
            reference, 
            new GlobalCoordinates(
                new Angle(50.0d), 
                new Angle(0.0d)
                ), 
            startBearing, 
            metersDistance
           );
```

I expected the Latitude (50.0) to remain the same, but it returns "49.7909857".
This may well be correct, but to my knowledge, regardless of Latitude, if you travel due east, you should remain on the same Latitude?

At a latitude of 0.0, the Latitude does indeed remain the same.

Is this a bug in the Library, or a lack of understanding on my part?

Comment: According to [Movable Type Script's Vincenty calculator](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) the latitude appears to drift a little.  I'm not a mathematician so I can not explain why this might be.  For a mathematical explanation try [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

The latitude is supposed to change!  90° is just your *initial* bearing.  In order to maintain a straight path (the definition of a geodesic), the path must bend away from the circle of latitude (unless it's the equator).  To help understand this, imagine a latitude so close to 90° that it's a circle of radius 1m about the north pole.