# Add a distance and bearing to a DbGeography to get a new point

Tags: c#, entity-framework, geospatial

I have a DbGeography representing a start point and I know a distance and direction of travel.  Given that information, is there a way to get a new DbGeography representing the new position using the SqlSpatial libraries? Ie without having to do the great circle calculations myself or use a 3rd party library.

I'm after something like

```
DbGeography newPosition = oldPosition.Add(distance, bearing);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but I think what you're after is an implementation of the Vincenty Direct Problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Direct_Problem

Have a look at

http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/free-source-code/geodesy-library-vincentys-formula/

and this related question [Vincenty Direct formula Latitude issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687723/vincenty-direct-formula-latitude-issue)

Hope this is of use.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of those. I've updated the question to reflect that I don't want to use other libraries beyond what SqlSpatial gives you, since it can already do those calculations if you have 2 DbGeography objects. Eg a.Distance(b) and a.Difference(b).

Comment: Thanks @Simon. I've a feeling the answer is no, there's nothing built in that does this. I had a google for C# equivalents to ST_Project (PostGIS) and Point_At_Bearing (Oracle) and found nothing for either DbGeography or SqlGeography :( Hopefully someone else will be able to help you out.